# Adjacency Matrix -> Directed graph -> DFS

Tags: java, depth-first-search, directed-graph, adjacency-matrix

This is the code my friends and I have come up with so far after fiddling around. What we are trying to do is read in the adjacency matrix (input.txt), then create a directed graph out of it so we can search it using Depth-First Search. We want the output of our program to provide the order of visited nodes.

The java code:
http://pastebin.com/bAzBadxi

The input.txt file:
http://pastebin.com/r72J34uA

My question is, what do we initialize "n" to? (line 32 in the java code)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a vertex object before you use it.

```
Vertex n;    // before g.addVertex(n);
```

I am not validating your algorithm, just removing compiler error, if your algo is correct it should work fine

Comment: Thanks, it did compile, but the algorithm is definitely lacking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to solve is a problem of topological sorting.

[Topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

In this case, it doesn't matter what n you initialize to, you can simply use the first vertex in the adjacency matrix as the start.

And adjacency matrix (which should be a square matrix) is a legit representation of a directed graph, you can use the matrix to search the graph directly.

Comment: Thanks. It compiles now, but nothing is showing up, even as I have changed the matrix to be square (thanks for the tip). Any hints on how we can fix it? Is there a way to set n to the first vertex in the adjacency matrix?